# KeyPressed and KeyReleased events for simplified chinese input are not received

Tags: java, swing

In my program I have a `TextField` to which I added a `KeyAdapter`. Inside the `KeyAdapter` I have overwritten the `keyTyped`, `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` method. These work without any problem for a german, or english keyboard layout but the `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` events are not triggered for number input with the simplified Chinese keyboard layout.

Here is a little example program:

```
public class ChineseInput extends JFrame
{

    public ChineseInput()
    {
        this.setTitle("Chinese Input Example");
        this.setSize(300, 200);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("KeyTyped: " + e.getKeyCode());
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("KeyPressed: " + e.getKeyCode());
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("KeyReleased: " + e.getKeyCode());
            }
        });

        this.add(textField);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            ChineseInput chineseInput = new ChineseInput();
            chineseInput.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

To reproduce the problem add the simplified Chinese language in Windows. You can do it like this:

1. Click the Start menu and select Settings.
2. Select Time & language.
3. Click Region & language in the left column.
4. Under Languages click the language you want as default and click Set as default.

Now change the mode to the Chinese mode via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and start the example program. Typing numbers in the `TextField` only results in the keyTyped event and not in the other two. Is this a bug in the `KeyAdapter` or what is the problem here?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but typically you add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` on the `JTextComponent`. `KeyListeners` do not work well together with the user pasting input into the field, drag-and-dropping input, ...

Comment: Do not rely on KeyPressed/Released - their presence/behaviour will vary depending on the OS. As a usual rule-of-thumb in my experience: if can get keyTyped without keyPressed/Released (You just tripped over such a case) and you can get keyPressed/Released without keyTyped (e.g. for keys that don;t generate a UNICODE char, like the F1..12 keys).

Comment: Not a comprehensive description, but most of the behaviour is described in [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) javadoc.